# How to get the input data format for RawInput of each HID controller?

Tags: windows, driver, hid, raw-input

Is there an official source where I can find the exact data format of each controller from the manufacturer?

I am now trying to take the data of an xbox one controller using RawInput api and WM_INPUT message approach, but there is no guidance that I know of for the bRawData array of HID whatsoever!

I need to know which element of the array corresponds to which button/axis, and bitmasks for buttons as well.

For xbox one, and for all major controllers and manufacturers as well. That's because I am trying to get input manually for a long story beyond the scope of this question. Any idea? Googling wasn't helpful.